getGEO not working
trying URL 'https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE22nnn/GSE22093/suppl//GSE22093_RAW.tar?tool=geoquery'
Content type 'application/x-tar' length 357324800 bytes (340.8 MB)
downloaded 137.1 MB

Error in getGEOSuppFiles("GSE22093") : 
  Failed to download E:/data/GSE22093/GSE22093_RAW.tar!

This error message appeared when I tried to download this dataset, I tried this function before and it worked, when I removed the files for some reason and tried again on the same PC and the same directory it didn't work,changed the directory didn't work, changed the permissions it didn't work out neither

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I could download the file from the above link ,its called GSE22093_RAW.tar. I suggest trying at a less busy time, e.g. weekend and considering whether there's a firewall issue blocking the download, e.g. download via tethering your mobile to you PC/laptop as a wifi hotspot. A firewall is the most likely explanation, NCBI do restrict/minimise bandwidth but not via ftp to my knowledge.
